# Dealing with "atomicity" in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, variables, concurrency

I'm working on an app with NodeJS and Mongodb and Mariadb.
Users can create votes for some actions. They are valid for a specific time. 
To have control whether a vote is valid or not, I store them inside a collection with their creation time, and start a timeout on the "oldest" vote, because it's about to expire first.
So if the timeout is over, the vote gets deleted and the next vote (if there is one stored) creates an timeout. If there is no vote left, nothing happens.
Therefore I need to check somehow, whether an timeout is running, so I just need to add the vote to the database or if in addition I need to create a timeout. To be more specific, if there is no entry in the database, I need to start the timeout. But this lookup in mongodb is not safe because there are no "transaction".

Here is my approach, but I think it is not safe:
I have an index file with:

```
let timeoutRunning = false;
activateTimeout = ()=>{timeoutRunning=true;}
deactivateTimeout = ()=>{timeoutRunning=false;}
module.exports = [timeout, activateTimeout, deactivateTimeout]
```

In another file:

```
const index = require("index.js");
const Vote = require("voteModel.js");

router.post("/createVote", (req, res)=>{
   //some other stuff
  let v = new Vote({voteId:1, type:0, iat:Date.now()})

  Vote.insertVote(v)
   .then((item)=>{
      console.log("adding vote ", v.voteId)
      //only set Timeout if there is no running
      if(!index.timeoutRunning){ // is index.timeoutRunning just a copy?
        index.activateTimeout();
        console.log(" creating timeout for vote ",v.voteId)
        setTimeout(()=>{handleExpiredVote(v.voteId, v.type)}, 100000)
    }

   })
   .catch((err)=>{
     console.log(err)
   })
})

handleExpiredVote = (voteId, type)=>{
  Vote.deleteVote(voteId).exec()
    .then((status)=>{
        console.log(status)
        console.log("Deleting Vote ", voteId)
        return Vote.getNextVote().exec()
    })
    .then((nextVote)=>{
        if(nextVote!= null){
            console.log("NEXT, creating timeout for vote ",nextVote.voteId)
            setTimeout(()=>{handleExpiredVote(nextVote.voteId, 
                            nextVote.type)}, 1000)
        }else{
            console.log("no votes left")
            index.deactivateTimeout();
        }
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

I know NodeJS is single threaded. But is this idea safe? what if there are is an access on the timeoutRunning variable beforethe activateTimeout function of another call is executed?

Whats the better way to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you just want your votes to expire and be destroyed after some time?

If you use mongoose, you could just add a 'expires' field, so no more code is required from you.

For example, if you want your vote to be valid only one day, you could do :

```
const VoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, expires: '1d' }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. That was also my first attempt. But I need to know when a vote gets deleted, because I need some further actions to do. I know there is some kind of watch stream in mongodb but only for Replica Sets.

Comment: ok so maybe you could just run a cron job once a day that will remove and return outdated votes, so you can add some logic there. It seems safer to me than using a setTimeout. Tell me if it's not clear I'll write a proper anwser.

Comment: also had this idea, but I don't want that case that a user wants to vote but the vote i already expired. Therefore I need to delet it as soon as its expired.

Comment: because of the event loop of nodjs the duration of a timeout shouldn't matter right?

Comment: but if for some reason your app crashes, your timeout will never be executed.

Comment: yes, then the sever restarts and initializes a timeout for the first entry in the db. if it is already expired that i gets deleted and the next vote is taken

Comment: From what I see here, your timeout only gets initialized when a new vote is called. I don't know what are your further actions after deletion, but I would personally refactor the whole thing to use one of the solutions I quoted here. Sry I couldn't help more.